# Django __in lowercase

Tags: django, tags, django-orm, django-database, django-taggit

I'm using [django-taggit](http://github.com/alex/django-taggit), which handles the attachment of tags to arbitrary content types.
I imported a large tag list, which contains many uppercase words, as well as lowercase words.

Now, I' trying to get objects of another class containing a set of tags, but I want to compare case insensitively. When I do this:

```
Media.objects.filter(tags__name__in=['tag1', 'tag2'])
```

objects containing e.g. the tag "Tag1" are not found, only those ones with "tag1" or "tag2".

Is there any possibility in the django orm to do something like:

```
Media.objects.filter(tags__name__iin=['tag1', 'tag2'])
```

that acts like "icontains"?

Comment: Sounds like your better bet is to spin through your tags and convert them all to lowercase.

Comment: well - yes, that would be possible, but does not solve the general problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no easy way to do it. I'm not 100% sure, You can try something like this for your problem.

```
from django.models import Q

q = Q()
for tag in tags.split():
    q |= Q(tags__name__iexact=tag)

Media.objects.filter(q)
```

Comment: Since you are using iexact match, you do not neet to use <string>.lower() http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/models/querysets/#iexact

Comment: This works, thank you. However, I would appreciate an __iin-operator in the Django ORM.