# django icontains with __in lookup

Tags: django

So I want to find any kind of matching given some fields, so for example, this is what I would like to do:

```
possible_merchants = ["amazon", "web", "services"]
# Possible name --> "Amazon Service"
Companies.objects.filter(name__icontains__in=possible_merchants)
```

sadly it is not possible to mix icontains and the __in lookup.

It seems to be a pretty complex query so if at least I could ignore case the name that would be enough, for example:

```
Companies.objects.filter(name__ignorecase__in=possible_merchants)
```

Any ideas?

P.D.: The queries I posted don't work, it's just a way to express what I need (just in case heh)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923589/django-in-lowercase

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can create querysets [with the `Q` constructor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) and combine them with the `|` operator to get their union:

```
from django.db.models import Q

def companies_matching(merchants):
    """
    Return a queryset for companies whose names contain case-insensitive
    matches for any of the `merchants`.
    """
    q = Q()
    for merchant in merchants:
        q |= Q(name__icontains = merchant)
    return Companies.objects.filter(q)
```

(And similarly with `iexact` instead of `icontains`.)

Comment: In case anyone needs this for a dynamic field name, use `q |= Q(**{'%s__icontains' % field_name: merchant})`

Answer (score 5):

I find it a cleaner approach using `reduce` and `or_` operator:

```
from django.db.models import Q
from functools import reduce
from operator import or_

def get_companies_from_merchants(merchant_list):
    q_object = reduce(or_, (Q(name__icontains=merchant) for merchant in merchant_list))
    return Companies.objects.filter(q_object)
```

This would create a list of `Q` objects querying the `name` to contain a single element in merchant list. This would happpen for all the elements in `merchant_list` and all these `Q` objects would be reduced to a single `Q` object having mutliple ORs which can be directly applied to the filter query.

Answer (score 4):

This is the approach that I adopted:

```
class MyManager(models.Manager):
    def exclusive_in(self, lookup, value_list):
        return self.filter(reduce(or_, (Q(**{lookup:_}) for _ in value_list)))
```

Here is now to use it:

```
Companies.objects.exclusive_in('name__icontains', possible_merchants])
```

It was inspired by other answers in this thread, as well as [Django filter queryset __in for *every* item in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8618068/django-filter-queryset-in-for-every-item-in-list#53252077).

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to simulate the actions that Django normally does for `iexact` queries (it converts both parts of the comparison statement to the upper case via SQL Upper function.

This way, the query will look like this:

```
Companies.objects.annotate(
    upper_name=models.Upper("name")
).filter(
    upper_name__in=[rchant.upper() for merchant in possible_merchants]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer from [Gareth Rees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674688/django-icontains-with-in-lookup/9674801#9674801) helped me a lot with a similar issue while using the [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io) package.

To use this with `django_filters` in generic way one could create a MultipleInputs filter like this:

```py
    class MultipleInputs(filters.BaseInFilter, filters.CharFilter):
        pass
```

Then use that in the filterset and use a custom filtering method:

```py
    from django.db.models import Q
    
    class MyFilter(FilterSet):
        search = MultipleInputs(field_name='longname', label='Text search',
            method='multiplesearch', 
            help_text="Free text search. May be a comma separated list of strings.")
 
        def multiplesearch(self, queryset, field_name, value):
            q = Q()
            for searchstring in value:
                arguments = {field_name+'__icontains' : searchstring}

                q |= Q(**arguments)
            return queryset.filter(q)
```

No MultiInputs fields can have comma separated inputs.
Also works if you inherit MyFilter but overwrite search with a Filter with a different field_name.

Answer (score 0):

using iregex would be:

```
regex = '|'.join(['match 1', 'match 2', 'match 3'])
Companies.objects.filter(name__iregex=f'({regex})')
```

You can even add lookaround so that matches are guaranteed to be individual words, rather than parts of other words with different meaning ie:

```
options = ['match 1', 'match 2', 'match 3']
regex_options = [f'(?<!\w){option}(?!\w)' for option in options]  # Adds lookaround
regex = '|'.join(regex_options)
Companies.objects.filter(name__iregex=f'({regex})')
```

lookaround (ie lookbehind + lookahead) will not incur in character consumption therefore it'll match with substrings starting or ending strings, that would't be possible with [^\w].