# In Django, how to filter a model using a list of values but each value can be used only once?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

(Scroll down for updates.)

I'm new to Django. I'm using Mezzanine 4.2.3 (Django 1.10.8 under the hood according to requirements.txt). I have a Postgres database of details about movies. I want to display 10 movies on a page.

I have 2 issues:

1. Each movie must be from a different country. So far, I can only get a list of 10 random countries from a larger list. I don't know how to use `.objects.filter()` in a way that makes sure there are no repeated countries.
2. Some movies are produced by more than one country, and they are contained as strings in the database, for instance `'Tajikistan,Papua New Guinea,Korea'`. But the `.objects.filter()` function only returns movies with a single country in it.

My current code in `views.py`:

```
from .countries import countries # this is a Python list of countries

class MoviesListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Movies

    def get_queryset(self):
        random_countries = []

        i = 0
        while i < 10:
            country_choice = random.choice(countries)
            if country_choice in random_countries:
                pass
            else:
                random_countries.append(country_choice)
            i += 1

        return Movies.objects.filter(production_countries__in=random_countries)[:10]
```

I've googled around and looked into the Django documentation but haven't been able to find solutions. What's the best way to do this? Must I connect to the database with psycopg2, use sql to get 10 movies that fit my criteria and then create a context from there, or does Django already have something for this?

**Update 21 Feb 2018, 10.30pm:** Thanks in part to @MVanOrder (which led me to this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674688/django-icontains-with-in-lookup), amongst others), The closest I've come to a solution is:

```
from django.db.models import Q
from .countries import countries # this is a Python list of countries

class MoviesListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Movies

    def get_queryset(self):
        random_countries = []

        i = 0
        while i < 10:
            country_choice = random.choice(countries)
            if country_choice in random_countries:
                pass
            else:
                random_countries.append(country_choice)
            i += 1

q = Q()
for country in random_countries:
    q |= Q(production_countries__icontains = country)

return Movies.objects.filter(q).distinct('production_countries')[:10]
```

This ensures that I get 10 movies, but their production countries are unique in that they are different concatenations of different countries, but they still repeat countries in `random_countries`.

I could increase the number of countries in `random_countries`, but it doesn't ensure that they aren't repeated in the result.

I've been trying to use `order_by()`, `distinct()`, `__contains`, `__in`, `Q()`, and `exclude()` in various permutations but still haven't figured it out.

I'd also like to skip `order_by()` if possible since I read that it takes up a lot, a lot of resources.

Let me know if I should throw in the towel and write raw sql.

Comment: For what it's worth, you can run raw SQL using Django's database connection: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/sql/

Comment: @AKX After a whole day trying this out, I gave up and went with your suggestion. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is the [__contains](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#contains) lookup type.  While the [__in](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#in) lookup type is checks that the value of a field is in a provided list or tuple(in your case it converts the string to a tuple containing the provided string), __contains checks that the string field contains the string you provide.

Comment: In this case, I do want the value of the field to match what's in a provided list though. Hence `__in`.

Comment: I apologize I misunderstood.  So [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674688/django-icontains-with-in-lookup) may be what you're looking for.  Combing __contains(or __icontains) with __in by iterating over the list and using a logical or operator to combine each iterations __contains results.

Comment: thanks. I think I'm getting closer but still stuck. I've updated the question above.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a better solution:

```
from django.db.models import Q
from .countries import countries # this is a Python list of countries

class MoviesListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Movies

    def get_queryset(self):
        random_countries = []

        i = 0
        while i < 10:
            country_choice = random.choice(countries)
            if country_choice in random_countries:
                pass
            else:
                random_countries.append(country_choice)
            i += 1

        q = Q()
        for country in random_countries:
            q |= Q(production_countries__iregex = r'(^|.+,)%s(,.+|$)' % country)

        return Movies.objects.filter(q).distinct('production_countries')[:10]
```

Rather than using a contains that is looking for a string that contains the series of characters in the searched country, you can use a regex.

The one shown above matches:

- (^|.+,) - The beginning of the string or at least one character followed by a comma.
- %s - Replaced with the country name
- (,.+|$) - A comma followed by one or more characters, or the end of the string.

This will ensure the string you're looking for is not a segment of a larger string in a list of comma separated values.

Comment: This still allows countries to be repeated. But I think, maybe it can't be done this way anyway. I gave up and wrote raw sql instead. Thank you so much for helping out though!