# django filters icontains with __in lookup

Tags: python, django

Similar to this question:
[django icontains with __in lookup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9674688/django-icontains-with-in-lookup/68746294#68746294)

I am attempting to filter a single field with multiple values using the django-filters package. For example, I have a model Content with field *paragraph*. I want to return the object if Content.paragraph contains string "McDonald" **or** Content.paragraph contains string "MacDonald". Essentially be able to pass multiple icontains to a single field. I would like to be able to pass theoretically infinite values, not just two. Thanks!